android:screenOrientation="portrait" is deprecated
Since android:screenOrientation="portrait" is deprecated, I need a solution to ensure that my app runs only in portrait mode. However, none of the methods, including the programmatic approach, are working. Could you provide a proper solution?

The ability to choose the screen orientation for the activity inside the AndroidManifest.xml is not deprecated.
You can read about the attribute here.
It does, however, give you a warning in the IDE when you choose this option, stating that:

Expecting android:screenOrientation="unspecified" or "fullSensor" for this activity so the user can use the application in any orientation and provide a great experience on Chrome OS devices

If you want to do this through the code, you can override onActivityCreated method and set the orientation there.
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
      activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}


android:screenOrientation="portrait" is not deprecated it is Discouraged
Android Lint will warn you about it but you can disable that by adding "DiscouragedApi" to the tools:ignore attribute list the manifest xml
e.g.
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="DiscouragedApi">



sensorPortrait: If you want to lock the orientation to portrait but also want to allow upside-down portrait mode (when the user rotates the phone 180 degrees), you can use sensorPortrait:


android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"


userPortrait: This restricts the orientation to portrait but also allows the user’s preference to override the lock (useful in cases where a system setting might control orientation).


android:screenOrientation="userPortrait"

